# Completeness of a system: For all $n$ and within an interval?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Why is the system $\sin((2n-1)x)$ for $n=1,2,\cdots$ complete in $L^2[0,\frac\pi2]$?

This means that the Euclidean norm converges for $n=1,2,\cdots$ and for all $x\in[0,\frac\pi2]$ How does one prove these things simultaneously?

Comment: What do you mean by "Euclidean norm converges for $n=1,2,\ldots$ and for all $x\in [0,\pi/2$"?

Answer (score 1):

The functions you have are the solutions of a classical eigenvalue problem on $[0,\pi/2]$:
$$
                      -f'' = \lambda f,\\
                       f(0)=0,\;\; f'(\pi/2)=0.
$$
In this case, the eigenvalues are $\lambda_n = (2n-1)^{2}$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, and the corresponding eigenfunctions are, up to multiplicative constants, $\sin((2n-1)x)$.
If you choose real numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$, the normalized solutions of the following eigenvalue problem on $[a,b]$ form a complete orthonormal basis of $L^{2}[a,b]$:
$$
                      -f'' = \lambda f,\\
                      \cos\alpha f(a)+\sin\alpha f'(a) = 0,\\
                      \cos\beta f(b) +\sin\beta f'(b) = 0.
$$
You can also choose periodic types of conditions.

Comment: Just to be sure, $\beta$ and $b$ can be distinct etc, yes? The problem in the question is with $\alpha=a=0$ and $\beta=b=\pi/2$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @jdods : Yes, the $a$ and $b$ are independent of $\alpha$, $\beta$. The $\alpha, \beta$ are just artificial ways of imposing conditions $Af(a)+Bf'(a)=0$ where $A$ and $B$ are real, and not both $A$ and $B$ are $0$--you can pose the problem that way instead at $a$ and $b$.